# How to check if any of a list elements is contained in a list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings `myList` (class names). I am iterating through file names and I wish to know if the file names contain any of the classes in the list.

I tried the following:

```
for file in os.llistdir(path):
    if any((for s in myList) in file):
        print(file)
```

For example, if the list is `myList=['aa', 'ab']` and the files are `fooaa.txt`, `fooab.txt`, `foocc.txt`, `foock.txt`, I expect the code to output:

> fooaa.txt
>
> fooab.txt

Is there a better approach? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right syntax to write your test using `any`:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if any(s in file for s in myList):
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need.

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if any(i in file for i in myList):
        print(file)
```

---

Or using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("|".join(myList))
for file in os.listdir(path)::
    if pattern.search(file):
        print(file)
```